# What are acting as weights in a convolution neural network?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, weights

Looking at some old notes I took on CNN's and I wrote down that the weights in a CNN are acting like filters in a CNN but to be honest I don't really know what the weights are acting as in a CNN and was wondering if someone could explain that clearly to me.

Comment: You asked me to re-open this post because you wanted to get a specific answer to your question, although this question is already although somehow implicitly answered in other posts. In any case, [if my answer below answers your question, you should accept it.](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: hi @PlayerUnknown_12, check out [this minicourse about CNNs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArPaAX_PhIs&list=PLkDaE6sCZn6Gl29AoE31iwdVwSG-KnDzF) by Andrew Ng, if you're interested. I found it very helpful. Starting from second video he discusses how filters of CNNs can learn to detect edges of the objects in the images

Answer (score 1):

There are many resources that answer your question, but, given that you're apparently new to machine learning (ML), deep learning (DL), and neural networks (NN), let me provide a simple answer that should clarify your doubts.

The term **weight** in the context of ML, DL, and NN is a synonym for **parameter** (sometimes, in some contexts, such as linear regression, it is also known as **coefficient**), which can be constant (i.e. do not change during, for example, learning/training) or learnable (i.e. change during the training/learning process). In a feedforward neural network (FFNN), with and without recurrent connections, the weights are the numbers on the connections between neurons in different or same layers. They are called **weights** to emphasize that their role is to weigh the effect of one neuron on the other.

In a CNN, the weights are the kernels/filters of the CNN, i.e. the matrices that you use to perform the convolution (or cross-correlation) operation in a convolutional layer. So, given that CNNs perform an operation that seems to be different than the linear combination followed by the non-linear activation function in FFNNs, you could think that the weights in a CNN are not very similar to the weights in FFNNs. However, this is not fully true, as CNNs can be viewed as FFNNs (with some specific structure): maybe [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/18796/2444) will provide you more info about this topic. So, your notes are right!

In my opinion, the best way to understand the role of the kernels (i.e. weights) of a CNN and all the details behind the convolution (or cross-correlation) operation is to first study some traditional computer vision and image processing techniques, so maybe you should pick a book that covers them.

In [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/21967/2444), I briefly try to describe what a CNN is and what it can be used for. There are other answers on this site, such as [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/21394/24445), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/12510/2444), and [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/21999/2444), which you may want to read, if not now later, to understand even more all the details of CNNs. A  decent reference book that covers CNNs (and other DL topics) is [Deep Learning](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html) by Ian Goodfellow et al.